# How can I convert ViewData to String in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I saved a string as viewdata in @ViewData["ShopURL"]


When I just render it in razor page like this:

```
<a id="ShopA" href="@ViewData["ShopURL"]">123</a>
```

It works well.


Now I want to do this that if the ShopURL is null or empty then the ShopA will not display.

So I make my code like this:

```
@{
            string ShopViewData= ViewData["ShopURL"].ToString();;
            var ShopURL = "";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ShopViewData))
                {
                    ShopURL = "<a id="ShopA" href='" + ShopViewData+ "'></a>";
                }
        }
        @Html.Raw(ShopURL)
```

The problem is the ShopViewData do not return what the string in @ViewData["ShopURL"],but just something strange like "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.LocalizedHtmlString".


So,how can I convert ViewData to String?

Comment: Are you actually having problems converting any `ViewData` to a string or just `LocalizedHtmlString`?  Because the title of the question says it's the former but in the question you ask about the latter.  Have you looked at the documentation of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.LocalizedHtmlString`?

Comment: @ViktorSeifert I just transfer Localizer to viewdata for I want to transfer the localizer to the PartialView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just simply wrap the anchor in the IF?

```
@{
    var shopUrl = ViewData["ShopURL"] as string;
}

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(shopUrl))
{
    <a id="ShopA" href="@shopUrl">Go to shop</a>
}
```

---

EDIT to better answer the question: Your code has syntax errors and you might be calling `ToString()` on null object which would result in exception, once fixed this code works perfectly in new 2.0/2.1 project **as long as ViewData["ShopURL"] is string passed from the controller**:

```
@{
    string ShopViewData = ViewData["ShopURL"]?.ToString();
    var ShopURL = "";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ShopViewData))
    {
        ShopURL = $"<a id='ShopA' href='{ShopViewData}'>he</a>";
    }
}
@Html.Raw(ShopURL)
```

Your problem is in the controller, you are not passing in string, you are passing in object of type `LocalizedHtmlString`, if you want to keep that you can't call ToString() on this object, you have to cast it to `LocalizedHtmlString` and get it's `Value` property.

```
@{
    var ShopViewData = ViewData["ShopURL"] as LocalizedHtmlString;
    var ShopURL = "";
    if (ShopViewData != null)
    {
        ShopURL = $"<a id='ShopA' href='{ShopViewData.Value}'>he</a>";
    }
}
@Html.Raw(ShopURL)
```

Comment: Aha,maybe you don't understand what I said.However,using the way you showed what "as string" is useful.Thank you!

Comment: I have editted the answer because you are clearly not working with a string inside the viewdata and looking for trouble even if you use the original answer.